# HTML/CSS -- Elipsise Breadcrumbs to the Left of a Logo

Tags: html, css, overflow, ellipsis

I am trying to put a breadcrumb bar next to a logo. The website is supposed to scale from 1000px to 400px, thus it would be good if I could ellipsise the breadcrumbs in case they're too long (starting a new line does not make much sense, as the breadcrumb text is horizontally aligned with the logo text).

Desired look as ASCII art:

*when all the text fits:*

```
  /-\
  \-/
COMPANY    Breadcrumb > Breadcrumb > Breadcrumb
```

*when scaled down:*

```
  /-\
  \-/
COMPANY    Breadcrumb > Breadcru...
```

My **HTML** currently looks like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="...">
        <img src="logo"/>
    </a>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; min-width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 100%;">
    <a href="..." style="margin: 0 0 0 100px;">Top Crumb</a>
    <span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="...">2nd Level Crumb</a>
    <span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="...">3rd Level Crumb</a>
</div>
```

Now, how can I apply the ellipsis to the last visible breadcrumb (without setting a fixed width for every `<span>` and `<a>`?

(I hope that's clear enough but I'd be more than happy to answer questions.)

Comment: If you set `max-width` less than your `min-width` doesn't the existing CSS rules you have defined create the ellipsis at the desired point?

Comment: Not so much, sadly... seems to affect only things directly within the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/C97kC/

Just remove `min-width: 400px`

CSS:

```
#div{
    position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="...">
        <img src="logo"/>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="div">
    <a href="..." style="margin: 0 0 0 100px;">Top Crumb</a>
    <span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="...">2nd Level Crumb</a>
    <span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="...">3rd Level Crumb</a>
</div>​
```

**Edit:**

If you want it to be at least 400px width, you can use the code you have. The problem is that the text wasn't long enough.

If you use...

```
<a href="..." style="margin: 0 0 0 100px;">Top Crumb</a>
<span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
<a href="...">2nd Level Crumb</a>
<span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
<a href="...">3rd Level Crumb</a>
<span>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;</span>
<a href="...">4rd Level Crumb</a>
```

...you will see the ellipsis.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C97kC/1/
​